# Python import module vs import _module

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

While configuring PyDev's [Forced Builtins](http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html#PyDevInterpreterConfiguration-ForcedBuiltins) in Aptana I noticed that some modules were referenced by default with an `_` (underscore) prefix.

So I open a Python interpreter and to my surprise, the imports below work:

```
import ast
import _ast
import bisect
import _bisect
import csv
import _csv
# ... and so on
```

Now if I do a `dir()` on the imported modules, I see different contents:

```
>>> dir(csv)
['Dialect', 'DictReader', 'DictWriter', 'Error', ...] # and so on
>>> dir(_csv)
['Dialect', 'Error', ...] # node that DictReader and DictWriter are missing
```

Finally, help() tells me they are clearly different modules:

```
>>> help(_csv)
Help on module _csv:

NAME
    _csv - CSV parsing and writing.

FILE
    /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/_csv.so
...

>>> help(csv)
Help on module csv:

NAME
    csv - CSV parsing and writing.

FILE
    /usr/lib64/python2.6/csv.py
...
```

So, what's the difference between `import module` and `import _module`?
Is there a convention behind it or something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some modules use *some* C code to implement parts that need the speed. The *main* module still uses Python glue, and the `_module` version contains the C extension.

See for example the [`csv.py` module](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/csv.py); it imports from the [`_csv.c` C library](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/_csv.c) for most of the functionality, with only the `Dialect`, `Sniffer`, `DictReader` and `DictWriter` classes implemented in pure Python.

The `module` plus `_module` convention is just that, a convention. Not all C extensions follow this pattern.

Answer (score 4):

`_module` is usually the part of module that is written in C. `module` is a python wrapper around it. You shouldn't ever need to import `_modules` yourself.